# Как выровнять по центру экрана заголовок? (по вертикали)

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

```css
#name {
  font-family: Comic Sans, Comic Sans MS, cursive;
  position: absolut;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu_conteiner">
  <nav id="menu_nav">
    <ul>
      <li class="menu_li"><a href="Main.html" class="menu"> Главная </a></li>
      <li class="menu_li"><a href="#m2" class="menu"> Меню_2 </a></li>
      <li class="menu_li"><a href="#m3" class="menu"> Меню_3 </a></li>
      <li class="menu_li"><a href="#m4" class="menu"> Меню_4 </a></li>
      <li class="menu_li"><a href="#m5" class="menu"> Меню_5 </a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
<div>
  <h1 id="name"> Название</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.hor-center {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex; 
  height: 200px; /*высота блока для примера работы.*/
  padding: 5px;
}

.hor-center {
  /*Вертикальное выравнивание*/
  -webkit-box-align: center; 
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.hor-center {
  /*Горизонтальное выравнивание*/
  -webkit-box-pack: center; 
  -ms-flex-pack: center;         
  justify-content: center; 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
  <title> Сайт </title>
  <link href="Main_style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

</head>

<body>
  <div id="menu_conteiner"> 
  </div> 
  
  <div class="hor-center">
    <h1 id="name"> Название </h1>
  </div>

  </body>
  </html>
```

Вариант №2:

```css
.hor-center {
    display: table;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
h1#name {
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
  <title> Сайт </title>
  <link href="Main_style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

</head>

<body>
  <div id="menu_conteiner"> 
  </div> 
  
  <div class="hor-center">
    <h1 id="name"> Название </h1>
  </div>

  </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Используя **flexbox** и `height: 100%`.

```css
#name {
   display: flex;
   height: 100%;
   align-items: center;
   /*justify-content: center;*/  /*для центрирования по горизонтали убрать коментарий*/
}
 
html, body {
    height:100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="name">
 заголовок
</div>
```

Если хотите и по горизонтали и по вертикали центрировать, то так - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EbrrrZ

Comment: Не работает(
Смещается к левому краю

Comment: @DoZa Play так вы сами написали что по вертикали.

Comment: У вас тег H1  не закрыт

Comment: @DoZa Play Если хотите и по вертикали центрировать и по горизонтали то можно так - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EbrrrZ

Comment: Добавил body, html { height: 100%; }, так точно сработает, добавил пример в код.

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин вы можете использовать "Фрагмент кода"

Comment: @Даниил Ага, как раз добавлял

Comment: А `flex` сейчас нормально во всех браузерах уже работает?

Comment: @МаксимСтепанов [ссылка](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/flex#Поддержка_браузерами)

Comment: @МаксимСтепанов и тут - https://htmlhook.ru/manual-flexbox-css.html

Answer (score 1):

```css
body{
  background: skyblue;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

header{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

#name{
  background: yellow;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

#name h1{
  font-family: Comic Sans, Comic Sans MS, cursive;;
  font-size: 2rem;
  text-align: center
}

#menu_conteiner{
  background: gray;
  padding: 1rem;
}

#menu_conteiner ul{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

#menu_conteiner li{
  padding-bottom: .5rem;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title> Сайт </title>
  <link href="Main_style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

</head>

<body>

<header>
  <div id="menu_conteiner">
    <nav id="menu_nav">
      <ul>
        <li class="menu_li"><a href="Main.html" class="menu"> Главная </a></li>
        <li class="menu_li"><a href="#m2" class="menu"> Меню_2 </a></li>
        <li class="menu_li"><a href="#m3" class="menu"> Меню_3 </a></li>
        <li class="menu_li"><a href="#m4" class="menu"> Меню_4 </a></li>
        <li class="menu_li"><a href="#m5" class="menu"> Меню_5 </a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>

  <div id="name">
    <h1> Название </h1>
  </div>
  
</header>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

В вашем контексте это будет выглядеть не очень. Вам стоит по лучше разъяснить что именно вы хотите.

**1.**

```css
#name {
  font-family: Comic Sans, Comic Sans MS, cursive;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu_conteiner">
  <nav id="menu_nav">
    <ul>
      <li class="menu_li"><a href="Main.html" class="menu"> Главная </a></li>
      <li class="menu_li"><a href="#m2" class="menu"> Меню_2 </a></li>
      <li class="menu_li"><a href="#m3" class="menu"> Меню_3 </a></li>
      <li class="menu_li"><a href="#m4" class="menu"> Меню_4 </a></li>
      <li class="menu_li"><a href="#m5" class="menu"> Меню_5 </a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
<div>
  <h1 id="name"> Название</h1>
</div>
```

**2.**

```css
body {
  position: relative;
}

#name {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  font-family: Comic Sans, Comic Sans MS, cursive;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu_conteiner">
  <nav id="menu_nav">
    <ul>
      <li class="menu_li"><a href="Main.html" class="menu"> Главная </a></li>
      <li class="menu_li"><a href="#m2" class="menu"> Меню_2 </a></li>
      <li class="menu_li"><a href="#m3" class="menu"> Меню_3 </a></li>
      <li class="menu_li"><a href="#m4" class="menu"> Меню_4 </a></li>
      <li class="menu_li"><a href="#m5" class="menu"> Меню_5 </a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
<div>
  <h1 id="name"> Название</h1>
</div>
```