# Как сделать адаптивными более одной картинки в блоке

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

[image: Блок с сеткой]

Подскажите пожалуйста как сделать такой блок что бы он был адаптивным, а верхняя картинка и текст центрировались и так же были адаптивными.

Код:

```css
.firstBG {
    padding: 0px; 
}
    
.firstCL {
    display: flex;
    height: 100%;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid firstBG">
  <img src="./img/firstBG.png" class="w-100"> 
</div>
  <div class="firstCL">
    <img src="./img/firstCenterLogo.png">
</div>
```

Comment: Как вы пытались это делать и что конкретно вызвало затруднения?

Comment: [Выравнивание по вертикали](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/753269/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83-%D1%8D%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8/753278#753278)

Comment: Делал при помощи бутстрапа, бекграунд адаптировал, а картинку и текст не понимаю как соединить к нему. Бекграунд делал в container-fluid с класом w-100. Первый раз делаю адаптивность, так что думаю что и это не совсем правильно.

Comment: @first try нужен воспроизводимый пример кода

Comment: @РашенБеар примерно так

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете использовать элемент **flex-wrap** со значением **wrap**. Пример:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
}

.flex-container>div {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 75px;
  font-size: 30px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="flex-container">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>  
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>  
  <div>7</div>
  <div>8</div>
  <div>9</div>  
  <div>10</div>
  <div>11</div>
  <div>12</div>  
</div>
<p>Пробуйте изменить размер окна.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Также для этого элемента вы можете использовать значение **row wrap**. Пример:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
}

.flex-container>div {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 75px;
  font-size: 30px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="flex-container">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>  
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>  
  <div>7</div>
  <div>8</div>
  <div>9</div>  
  <div>10</div>
  <div>11</div>
  <div>12</div>  
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Спецификация **[W3 CSS Flexible Box Layout Module](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp)**.